# OpenCart > Checkout > Address dropdowns don't show full address

Tags: opencart

The shipping and billing address dropdowns during OpenCart checkout (existing addresses, logged in user) don't show items such as company name, address line 2 and post code. In fact it appears to me that the optional/non-mandatory fields are not shown in the dropdown.

How do I fix it? Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go to `*ayment_address.tpl & shipping_address.tpl`

Go to: `../public_html/catalog/view/theme/[default]/template/checkout/payment_address.tpl/shipping_address.tpl`

Find & Replace:

`<?php echo $address['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $address['lastname']; ?>, <?php echo $address['address_1']; ?>, <?php echo $address['city']; ?>, <?php echo $address['zone']; ?>, <?php echo $address['country']; ?>`

With:

`<?php echo $address['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $address['lastname']; ?>, <?php echo $address['company']; ?>, <?php echo $address['address_1']; ?>, <?php echo $address['address_2']; ?>, <?php echo $address['city']; ?>, <?php echo $address['zone']; ?>, <?php echo $address['country']; ?>, <?php echo $address['postcode']; ?>`

This has worked for me in Opencart 2.0.1.1